# Propertysheet Dialog box not dispaly propery in Windows 7

Tags: mfc

I have an application which has Propertysheet dialog box with PropertyPage and dialogbox has three button at the bottom.
PropertySheet and PropertyPage create using MFC CProperySheet and CpropertyPage.

Dialog box display fine in windows xp but in windows 7 its partially cut three button

Please Help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the font size being something other than default size (check the DPI in the Display properties). If you're manually sizing the property sheet you'll need to be aware that the dialog units will be multiplied by a factor to calculate the size for a given DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify:

Are you embedding property sheet in a dialog?

If yes:

1. Is there any reason to do so?
2. The buttons you mention belong to a dialog or property sheet?
3. Are you resizing property sheet?
4. If buttons belong to the dialog are they cut by the bottom of the dialog?

The best if you post a snapshot of the dialog from XP and 7.

Comment: No I am not embedding propertysheet in a dialog. There is PropertySheet Dialog and inside it has property page. As I am not able to insert image please follow the link "http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/246c5bc4-df49-4d00-a5dd-718f0ab6588f/#15f72008-d9ab-4ce0-89ae-8827cf67d767"